# Function of "\numexpr\totvalue{<counter>}"

Tags: counters, totcount

The code below is found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347471/168676). It works normally: if  `\numexpr\totvalue{<counter>}`is replaced by `\the<counter>` the result is wrong (0).

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{totcount}
 \newtotcounter{totalpoints}
 \setcounter{totalpoints}{0}

 \begin{document}

 Total points are \the\numexpr\totvalue{totalpoints}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item [5 points]\addtocounter{totalpoints}{5} Here is the first question.
 \item [6 points]\addtocounter{totalpoints}{6} Here is the second.
 \end{enumerate}


 \end{document}
```

I find that  if the usual `\the<counter>`is placed after  the last incrementation it provides the result properly.

Could someone explain what  these two commands do?
`\totvalue`is most likely what allows the command for writing the number to be put anywhere in the source code but it might have some other use in this code, and in that case I'd like to know what it is.
As for `\numexpr`,  in two  cases of use that I tried this command  is not needed, *nor is it needed in the code shown above*. Is this a TEX primitive? a LATEX command? What does it do generally? Why has it been added in the code above? In prevision of what possible problem has it been added?

Comment: \the<counter> is a representation, not a value. `\the\numexpr\value{<counter>}` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The point is not whether `\the\numexpr\value{<counter>}` works or not and it surely doesn't when substituted in the above code to `\the\numexpr\totvalue{<counter>}`, but it is, except that `\totvalue`is most likely what allows the command for writing the number to be put anywhere in the source code, what is the use of `\numexpr`? Is that a TEX command?…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General explanation:

In LaTeX2e,

- `\newcounter{<counter>}` creates a count register `\c@<counter>` with initial value 0.
- `\(ref)stepcounter{<counter>}` and `\addtocounter{<conter>}{<num>}` changes the value stored in `\c@<counter>`.
- `\the<counter>` prints the value stored in `\c@<counter>`, by default in arabic style (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...).

Package `totcount` extends the counter concept by registering two count registers in using `\newtotcounter{<counter>}`.

- The first, `\c@<counter>` is registered by `\newcounter{<counter>}` and acts the same as LaTeX2e counters.
- The second, `\c@<counter>@totc` is registered by `\regtotalcounter{<counter>}`.
- The value in `\c@<counter>@totc` is in sync with that in `\c@<counter>` and is written to `.aux` file at the end of document, and is read at the beginning of document.
- Hence starting from the second run, `\c@<counter>@totc` holds the value of `\c@<counter>` at the end of last run.

#### Specific to the linked answer:

In the linked [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347471) to question *Total number of points*,

- When the `.tex` file is run for the second time, at the beginning of document, the value of `\c@totalpoints` is 0 (because of `\setcounter{totalpoints}{0}`), but the value of `\c@totalpoints@totc` is 11 (5 + 6).
- When you ues `\thetotalpoints` to replace `\the\numexpr\totvalue{totalpoints}`, the value of `\c@totalpoints` is print, which is 0.
- (Recommended) When you use `\total{totalpoints}` to replace `\the\numexpr\totvalue{totalpoints}`, the value of `\c@totalpoints@totc` is print, hence you get 11.
- When you use `\totvalue{totalpoints}`, you get the value of `\c@totalpoints@totc`, and you need prefix `\the` to print that value.
- The `\numexpr`, a primitive originally introduced by eTeX (see [*The eTeX Manual*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf), section 3.5) and now supported by all popular TeX engines, is used to writing number expressions. In the linked answer the `\numexpr` is not necessary.

To sum up, to print the total value of a counter (registered by `\newtotcounter` or extended by `\regtotalcounter`), using `\total{<counter>}` is enough.

Comment: Very instructive answer! Thank you!